# React router works only with Chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have a problem with the routes of my React application in the production environment, they only work with Chrome. In all the other browsers the routes are always redirected to the LoginPage component. I don't understand why in the development environment the routing worked for all browsers.

I have my routes like this:

```
<Switch>
  <GuestRoute
    location={location}
    path="/signup"
    exact
    component={SignupPage}
  />
  <GuestRoute
    location={location}
    path="/forgot_password"
    exact
    component={ForgotPasswordPage}
  />
  <GuestRoute
    location={location}
    path="/reset_password/:token"
    exact
    component={ResetPasswordPage}
  />
  <UserRoute
    location={location}
    path="/"
    exact
    component={DashboardPage}
  />
  <GuestRoute location={location} component={LoginPage} />
</Switch>
```

Three of these components use Redux, so i tried to fix the problem using the wrapper "withRouter" according to [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration). But did not worked.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: according to your explanation it sounds like you have different server configurations in development and production ... Did you setup any specific rules in your nginx/apache configs?

Comment: Do you have a public repo with your project? This way I can look into this problem in more detail and even test what might go wrong there.

Comment: You may be having a known issue, try adding https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ as per an issue listed on github. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4999

Comment: The app is being served directly from NodeJS. Here's a public repo of the app [link](https://github.com/Jaime691/lmla_ui.git).

Comment: About the polyfill, I already tried to insert the script tag in the index.html but I'll try to install it as a dependency.

Comment: It seems we are working on very similar projects! ;)

Comment: I have commited to your repo ... Feel free to ask me anytime you have a problem with your code.

The bug was not located in the Router component, but in an error case of a validation function. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your recommendations and advice but I'm still having the problem with the routing in safari and other browsers. I just update and simplified the repo to show more easily the problem. 

Please pull the repo and run the server. 

Then try localhost:3000/signup in Chrome and Safari, Firefox or IE to see the issue.

Comment: Found the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#other-solutions). Sorry for all the troubles!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to change the way the static files are served.

Before:

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/build`));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

After:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Thanks to Michel, who helped me to find my bug.